# How to post data using Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

[Data from add pop up must get saved here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC9uO.jpg) [This is my add popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTFEj.jpg) I am very new to Angular 2. I am unable to post the data.. It is giving error as "department_id,category_id,subcategories,times are missing". I am unable to fetch the data from the selected list.I am here by sharing my code please help.
Here is my code of ts:

Component.ts file:

```
addTask(new_task,task) {
  console.log(new_task);
  task.department_id =  new_task.department_id, 
  task.category_id =  new_task.category_id, 
  task.client_id =  new_task.client_id, 
  task.project_id =  new_task.project_id
  this.currentTask = true;
  this.playTimer();
   this.newTask.hide();

                    this.ApiService
                      .addtimerEntries(new_task)
                      .subscribe(
                        entry  => {
                          this.entries = entry;
                          console.log(entry);
                         console.log(this.entries);
                          this.entries.map(function(entry) {
                            var total = 0;
                            entry.total = moment.utc(total).format("HH:mm");
                          })    
                        },
                        error => {
                           console.log(error);
                        }); 
                    }
```

Api service code:

```
        addtimerEntries(new_task){
var company_id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('company_id'));
  var email = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userEmail'));
  var start = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('start'));
  var date = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('date'));
  var department_id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('department_id'));
  var category_id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('category_id'));
  var subcategory_id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('subcategory_id'));
  var option_id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('option_id')); 

  var data = {
    workEmail:email,
    company_id:company_id,
    entry_type:"checkin_entry",
    department_id:new_task.department_id,
    category_id:new_task.category_id,
   "subcategories":[{
       subcategory_id:new_task.subcategory_id ,
           option:new_task.option_id
    }] ,
    "times": [{
            state:"start",
            date:"dd/mm/yyyy"
         }]  
  }
  return this.http.post(timerUrlBase + '/timerEntry' , data, options)
                  .map(this.extractData)
                  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

My HTML part:

```
<div class="table-container">
                    <table class="tasks-table" md-row-select="selected">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr md-auto-select *ngFor="let tod of todays.today">
                                <td class="category-cell"> {{tod.department_id}} </td>
                                <td class="subcategory-cell"> {{tod.category_id}} </td>
                                <td class="client-cell"> {{tod.client_id}} </td>
                                <td class="project-cell"> {{tod.project_id}} </td>
                                <td class="duration-cell"> {{tod.total_hours}}</td>
                                <td class="icon-cell-one">
                                    <span mdTooltipPosition="above" mdTooltip="Press to restart task">
                                    <md-icon class="wd-reload-icon" svgIcon="refresh"></md-icon>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

console output:

```
Object {status: "success", data: Array(1)}
data:Array(1)
0:Object
category_id:Object
company_id:2
department_id:10
entry_type:"checkin_entry"
subcategories:Array(1)
times:Array(1)
workEmail:"test1@test.com"
_id:"592bbd40325a5a0786f66137"
__proto__:Object
length:1
__proto__:Array(0)
status:"success"
__
```

Comment: Can you share the full code of your service?

Comment: Have you tested the service directly without using Angular, such as via Postman? Also using the chrome dev tools check what is happening on the network tab when this request executes. It will show the request object as it is being sent.

Comment: @ Suneet Bansal: Hai, i had pasted full what i had written in service

Comment: @benPearce Ya i had checked it with postman it is working fine.

Comment: @benPearce: in network tab it is showing error with 500 as "{"message":"department_id,category_id,subcategories,times are missing","error":{}}"

Comment: What does the request object on the request with the 500 response show? Are those properties missing or not valued?

Comment: @benPearce : it is showing as" 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: Under the Header tab, there is a Request Payload, this will show the JSON representation of your request.

Comment: seems, you are not having those three missing values in `localStorage`

Comment: @benPearce: In request payload its showing : {workEmail: "test1@test.com", company_id: 2, entry_type: "checkin_entry", department_id: null,…}
category_id
:
null
company_id
:
2
department_id
:
null
entry_type
:
"checkin_entry"
subcategories
:
null
workEmail
:
"test1@test.com"

Comment: @ sravan: I had declared those in localStroage as well, but i am not sure what i had written is right or wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error, you are missing `department_id`, `category_id` and `subcategories`

You don't have those values in `localStorage` check the chrome `localStorage`

You can check from browser,

Open **`console ==> Application ==>  LocalStorage`** and check

Change your service to,

```
addtimerEntries(user){
    var company_id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('company_id'));
    var email = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userEmail'));
    var start = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('start'));
    var number = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('number'));
    var department_id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('department_id')) || '';
    var category_id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('category_id')) || '';
    var subcategories = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('subcategories')) || [];

    var data = {
        workEmail:email,
        company_id:company_id,
        entry_type:"checkin_entry",
        department_id:department_id,
        category_id:category_id,
        subcategories:subcategories
    }
    var times = {
        state:start,
        date:number
    }
    console.log(times);
    return this.http.post(timerUrlBase + '/timerEntry' , data, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Watch the lines,

```
var department_id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('department_id')) || '';
var category_id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('category_id')) || '';
var subcategories = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('subcategories')) || [];
```

**I have taken empty values, if the values are null**

Comment: Thanks for the help, after changing code given by you, the null values had become empty. but its showing errors in console like this "workEmailcompany_iddepartment_id,department_idcategory_id,category_idsubcategoriesentry_typetimes,time are missing"

Comment: pls share the code, how you added data to `localStorage`, in which console you are getting the error?

Comment: so, your code to ad data to local storage seems to be wrong, pls share that code...

Comment: still, I am unable to see the code, where you set the values into local-storage, 
Eg:  `localStorage.getItem('company_id',5)`

Comment: it must fetch the id from server as soon as i login so i had given only "localStorage.getItem('company_id')"

Comment: sorry, to set the item into localstorage, you should use,  `setItem`
`localStorage.setItem('company_id','value from server')`

Comment: I had changed my code in service page as edited in code. Please check whether it is right or wrong.but getting the same error as 500

Comment: `console.log(response)` and `console.log(this.Auth)` and check the response

Comment: but in request Payload its showing :{workEmail: "test1@test.com", company_id: 2, entry_type: "checkin_entry"}
company_id
:
2
entry_type
:
"checkin_entry"
workEmail
:
"test1@test.com"

Comment: what response you are getting?

Comment: It is not displaying anything in console. Those lines are only not taken.i also made it run line by line in services, those lines are not taken

Comment: so, it is going to catch, comment that code and replace it with .

`return this.http.post(timerUrlBase + '/timerEntry' , data, options)
                 .map(response => {
                    console.log(response)
                  })
                  .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                  });`

Comment: i had written like this:return this.http.post(timerUrlBase + '/timerEntry' , data, options) 
                   .map(response => { console.log(response) }) 
                  .catch(this.handleError);
}if i use this .catch(error => { console.log(error) }); it shows error as it is not assignable to parameter of type(err:any) so unable to run

Comment: I want to check the error, so please write, `.catch(error => { console.log(error) })`

Comment: response i got in console "Response {_body: "{"message":"department_id,category_id,subcategories,times are missing","error":{}}", status: 500, ok: false, statusText: "Internal Server Error", headers: Headers…}"

Comment: ok, let me explain the issuse, for your api call, you need `department_id,category_id,subcategories`, you need them before the api call.
So localstorage should be set befor that api is called

Comment: You should have those values prior to this call, either from a form, or from another api response. Got my point?

Comment: in the very starting of this code i had declared, i don no whether it is right or not, do i need to change from that itself?

Comment: do one thing, add some satic data into  data object from the database and call the api.

 `var data = {
    workEmail:'email',
    company_id:4,
    entry_type:"checkin_entry",
   department_id:5,
    category_id:10,
    subcategories:[]`

Comment: Ya i got what you told but i am not getting how to write, i also shared my html part once have a look please

Comment: ya i had done Get, its working, but i am unable to post the data

Comment: pls tell the exact requirement of you?

Comment: I have add button, inside that Department,Category,Subcategory are the fields, i have values for each field i had fetched from database, but now the selected values of those fields must get posted on the table

Comment: so, you mentioned  `selected values`, what does it mean? where you selected?

Comment: In add button there are 3 fields namely,Department,Category,Subcategory , in each field via dropdown i get few values, in that i select one value in all 3 fields, and in the table those values have to get posted

Comment: i had shared 2 pics pls see once

Comment: you should post the selected values in the form into the api, using `ngModel` or what ever the form type you use..

Comment: Ya even that i had done:<div class="form-group">
                            <ng-select [options]="departments" [(ngModel)]="new_task.department_id" placeholder="Department" [allowClear]="true" name="department" class='filterDropDown tracking' (selected)="selectDepartment($event)" (deselected)="unSelected()" required>
                            </ng-select>
             </div>

Comment: i am able to get the output in console but its showing error as entries.map is not a function

Comment: is this comment related to here?

Comment: Object {status: "success", data: Array(1)}
data
:
Array(1)
0
:
Object
category_id
:
Object
company_id
:
2
department_id
:
10
entry_type
:
"checkin_entry"
subcategories
:
Array(1)
times
:
Array(1)
workEmail
:
"test1@test.com"
_id
:
"592bbd40325a5a0786f66137"
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
status
:
"success"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Ya, in console i got this but i am not getting how to display this in my page

Comment: since `data` is an array, you should use, `response.data[0].company_id`, `response.data[0].department_id` etc...

Comment: Sure, I am here to help. :)

Comment: the output you have shown in the previous comment, is o/p of `console.log(this.entries);`?

Comment: In which page you want to display that? where is that HTML?

Comment: ya, i am getting the same output for both, console.log(this.entries); and console.log(entry);

Comment: In  HTML part i had wrote html code, in that table the entries must be added

Comment: why did you take `*ngFor="let tod of todays.today"` isn't it should be ``*ngFor="let tod of entries"`,  from where you got `today`?

Comment: "todays" was the dummy array entry which i had given before api integration. so in backend they have written code for that variable,today and previous are the 2 tables i have taken as i had shown in screenshot

Comment: where are you displaying `response data`, `entries` variable should be used to display data

Comment: i replaced this.entries with this.todays.today but i got error as "Error trying to diff '[object Object]'"

Comment: [Let us discuss here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145344/how-to-post-data-using-angular-2)

Comment: instead of response i have used extractData, its extracting but unable to post

Comment: Sorry, i don have 20 reputation to discuss in the link provided

Comment: okay, can you tell me exact requirement and scenario please. I am confused between `entries` and `today`

Comment: I need to post the data in the table but now i somehow managed to get output in console. entries is the new var i have used here, and through todays.today data must get posted to table

Comment: add this line below `console.log(this.entries)`, `this.todays.today = this.entries.data`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145345/discussion-between-sravan-and-tulsi).